# Full HTML code from iframes using webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I need get the html code this site (with C#):

http://urbs-web.curitiba.pr.gov.br/centro/defmapalinhas.asp?l=n (only works with IE8)

Using the WebClient class, or HttpWebResquest, or any other library, I do not have access to the html code generated dynamically.
So my only solution (I guess) would be to use the WebBrowser Control (WPF).

[image]

I was trying and trying, using mshtml.HTMLDocument and SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2
but it is a mess, I can not find what I want on it

it seems there are many "iframe", and inside there are more "iframe".
I do not know, I tried:

```
  IHTMLElementCollection elcol = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
  var test = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HTML");
  var test2 = doc.all;
```

but had no progress, does anyone know how to help me?

Observation / trivia: This is the site that shows where all bus pass in my city. This site is horrible, and only works in IE8 has serious problems. I would like to use this information to try to create a better service, using google maps or bing maps posteriorly.

The site that I was trying to get the information is no longer available, the idea to get dynamic html source code was abandoned and I cannot found the solution using a WebBrowser Control for WPF.

I believe that today there are other ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "Frames" object in the WebBrowser control, this object collection will return all frames and iframes if I recall correctly, and you need to look at the frames collection for each newly discovered frame you find on the page, get me? So, it’s like a recursive discovery loop that you need to run, you add each frame you find to your array or collection, and for each "unsearched" frame, you must look at that frames ".Frames" collection (they will all have a .Count etc, just a typical collection) and you do this for every newly discovered frame that you find, until of course, there are no longer any newly discovered frames that haven't had their ".Frames" collection searched.

So, the function, if done as per above, will allow for infinitely nested frames to be discovered, as I've done this in a VB6 project (I'm happy to give you the source for it if you would like it). However, the nesting is not preserved in my example, but that is ok since the nesting structure isn't important and you should figure out which was what by the order of the frames that are added to the collection since the order is related to the hierarchy of the frames being added.

Once you do that, getting the html source on this is pretty straight forward and I’m sure you know how to do, probably a .DocumentText depending on the version of the WB control you are using.

Also, you say it is not possible to use the HTTP clients to directly grab the source code? I must disagree, since once you have the frame objects, you can get the URLs from each frame object and do a URL2String type call to get the URL and turn it into a string from any httpclient-like class or framework. The only way it may be prevented on their behalf if if they accept requests only from a particular referrer (ie: the referrer must be from their domain name on some of their files etc), or the USER_AGENT where if it isn't one of the specified browsers, then it is technically possible that they will reject and not return data, unlikely but possible.

However, both referrer and user_agent can be changed in the httpclient you are using, so if they are imposing limits based on this sort of stuff, you can spoof them very easily and give them the data that they expect. Once again, this is low probability stuff, but it is possible they may have set things up this way especially if their data is proprietary.

PS: My first visit to the site ended up in IE crashing and reopening that tab :), terrible site I agree.